# How can i check repeated items in color.xml Android

Tags: android, xml-parsing

I want to write different colors to my Listview. How can i select only unrepeated colors?

i already tried with my codes but its still not finding repeated colors.

Thanks.

Edited:

now i have one appColors.xml, and it has around 250 Color's hexCode. I want show xml's hexCode items in ListView. I can show all xml items values in listview but i want show only not repeated hexcodes in my listview. So, how can remove repeated items?

```
Field [] fields = R.color.class.getDeclaredFields();
    String [] names = new String[fields.length];
    String [] values = new String[fields.length];
    int [] colors = new int [fields.length];

    try
    {
        for(int i=0; i<fields.length; i++)
        {       
            used=false;

            if(i>1){
            for(int k=0; k<i-1; k++ ){


                if(getString(fields[i].getInt(null)).equals((getString(fields[k].getInt(null))))){
                    used=true;
                    break;
                }

            }}

            if(used==false){

                names [i] = fields[i+3].getName();                          
                colors [i] = fields[i+3].getInt(null);
                values [i] = getString(fields[i+3].getInt(null));

            }           

        }

    }
        catch (Exception ex){}

    for(int i=0;i<fields.length-4;i++){

        addClass.adding(values[i], i+1, colors[i]);    
    }
```

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't understand what you are trying to do. Could You explain with a little more detail?

Comment: can you have a list of colors where colors are already different ?

Comment: i have around 200 color, some colors hexCodes are same. i  just remove  repeated hexcodes

Comment: You have to use the Array list instead of Array cause you want to remove the repeated element and just want to get the unique one so first you fill all elements in your Array list then compare each element to your whole Array list if you found that more then once and not on it own index then remove that item from your array list at last you got the different color in your array list.

Comment: And another good practice is that you have to use a database and select your color with respect to the distinct then move in your String array or Array list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code instead , I test it , works fine.

```
Field [] fields = R.color.class.getDeclaredFields();

ArrayList<String> colorNames = new ArrayList<String>();
String colorName;
try
{
    for(int i=0; i<fields.length; i++)
    {       
        colorName = getResources().getString(fields[i].getInt(null));
        if(!colorNames.contains(colorName))
        {
            colorNames.add(colorName);
            //this is a unique color name
            //process it here
        }
    }

}
catch (Exception ex){
    //Handle exception
}

for (String string : colorNames) {
    Log.i("COLOR", string);
    // Get your colors here
}
```

Comment: example <color>#fff</color><color>#aaa</color><color>#fff</color> i will show one time #fff and #aaa

Comment: All colors inside colorNames are unique, So if you have #fff , #fff, #000 so in the colorName it is two item, #fff and #000

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks a bit complex. Here is my suggestion 
Make a color file with a structure like this.

```
 <string-array name="color_list">  
    <item>black#000000</item>
    <item>blue#0000FF</item>
</string-array>
```

to read the colors you do it like

```
String[] myColorList = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.color_list);
Map uniqueColorList = new HashMap();
for(int i=0;i<myColorList.length;i++)
{
    String []colorAndVaue = myStrings[i].split("#");
    System.out.println("name "+ colorAndValue[0] + " value:" colorAndValue[1]);
    uniqueColorList.put(colorAndValue[1],colorAndValue[0]);
}
```

Comment: but i m using Reflections,

Comment: Field [] fields = R.color.class.getDeclaredFields();  how i will convert split("#")method to Field[]?